# Turning off tooltips in xfce

Tags: xfce

How can I turn off all tooltips in xfce (version 4.10)?

Or (if this is easier): How can I turn off the tooltip for a launcher icon?

Comment: This kind of question is more suitable for SuperUser; SO is for programming questions, not WM config questions. You'll get much more help on SU, hence the move vote. Don't be dissuaded `:)`.

Answer (score 3):

Done, I have updated to make complete answers below.

> How can I turn off all tooltips in xfce (version 4.10)?

According to [this forum thread](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7714), all tooltips on Xfce could be disabled for system wide by following the steps below.

- Create a new file `.gtkrc-2.0` in the Home directory of current user (unless the file exist already)
- Open the file in a text editor, and type `gtk-enable-tooltips = 0`
- Save and close the file
- Log out from current session, then log in again

After you log in, the tooltips will no longer appear anywhere on the system. I have tested this with Xfce 4.8 and 4.10, and it works as reported in Xubuntu. However, some users reported that this doesn't work well in Debian Xfce.

That's it.

**If you wish to keep the tooltips, but just make them smaller, try this:**

Instead of `gtk-enable-tooltips = 0`, enter the following lines into said  `.gtkrc-2.0` file (from the same forum thread - works for Debian Xfce 4.10):

```
style "xfdesktop-icon-view" {
    XfdesktopIconView::tooltip-size = 48
}
widget_class "*XfdesktopIconView*" style "xfdesktop-icon-view"
```

> Or (if this is easier): How can I turn off the tooltip for a launcher icon?

With Xfce 4.10 and newer, you can achieve these easily.

### For launcher icon on Desktop

- Go to **Settings > Desktop**
- Then go to **Icons - Appearance**
- Look for "Show icon tooltips" and deselect (leave the checkbox empty)

### For launcher icon on Panel

- Go to **Settings > Panel**
- Then go to **Items** and make selection on **Launcher** in the list
- Click on the *gear icon* on the right to run the Launcher setting dialog
- Under **Advanced**, look for "Disable tooltips" and deselect (leave the checkbox empty)

### For launchers in Applications Menu (Panel item)

- Go to **Settings > Panel**
- Then go to **Items** and make selection on **Applications Menu**
- Click on the *gear icon* on the right to run the Applications Menu setting dialog.
- Under **Appearance**, look for "Show applications descriptions in tooltip" and deselect (leave the checkbox empty)

Some Xfce components do not have tooltip option, such as for Window Buttons (tooltip cannot be disabled) and Whisker Menu (there isn't any tooltip for launchers, only application description).

But at least you can disable the tooltip for items above by graphical method.